# Redmine auto closing issues

Tags: git, redmine

I am new to using Redmine for my issue tracking. I am using GIT as my repository.
Lately I realised that Redmine is auto closing some issues for me.

I don't know why. Is it some sort of settings?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

In Redmine's standard configuration, the words `fixes` and `closes` within a commit message will automatically set any issues mentioned by the hash sign and their issue id (e.g. `#123`) to closed.

Please refer to [1]. This behaviour can be configured via **Administration** -> **Settings** -> **Repositories**.

[1] http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Referencing-issues-in-commit-messages

Comment: I actually read about this. However, I didn't find any fixes or closes in my comments. All I did was merging branches. In any case, is it possible to disable the function you mentioned?

Comment: Yes it's possible to disable it. Check the settings page and have a look what keywords and entries are active. I've edited jans post with a screenshot and explanatio (has to be reviewed first)